# I need a loop in my jquery snippet

Tags: jquery, html

I need this code to run again after the `$('.mp3').show();` is executed.

```
$('.mp3').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        $('object').remove();
        $('.mp3-0').show();
    });
});

$('.mp3-0').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        $('#mp3obj').replaceWith('<object width="0" height="0"> <param name="src" value="musicasite.mp3"> <param name="autoplay" value="false"> <param name="controller" value="true"> <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"> <embed src="musicasite.mp3" autostart="false" loop="false" width="0" height="0" controller="true" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></embed> </object>');
        $('.mp3').show();
    });
});​
```

What this whole snippet is doing for me is removing a song from the website when the user requests, but if this user wants it back then the music plays again.

But, after the code runs all this long it just stops working.

What I need is: the whole HTML file needs to be set as it was before the button was clicked and the code ran.

----- edit ------

An example can be seen here: http://dev.webtoad.com.br/toquedemagica/2012/
The page is in brazilian portuguese, but if you click on 'Parar música' and 'Tocar música' you can see what I have achieved so far.

Comment: I don't think toggle() works that way, and if you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, that version of toggle() is deprecated anyway?

Comment: I don't know, I'm learning jQuery yet and using api.jquery.com a lot, so I thought it was ok to use... But, it's not? What should I use?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that toggle() function? As a sidenote, once you remove an element, it's gone, and you'll have recreate it, including all and any event handlers.

Comment: So I would have to do that by hard coding the HTML tag again? Or by jquery?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to replace one link with the other one, one stops the song, the other plays it.

Comment: The two click functions are on different classes, so why do you need the toggle function at all? Just remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Because I need those links to switch from stop music to play music. I assumed this toggle could do the work for me, as I click it, it will be gone and replaced for the other link. What are the other ways to do so? Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making two big mistakes:

**1.** You'r not using toggle right. You want to toggle just the button visibility not the button behavior. That should be `$(this).toggle()` and then the rest of the actions outside of the toggle function. As you are clicking on two different buttons thought, there's not even much sense in using toggle at all, as it could get you into unexpected show/hide behaviors.

**2.** On the `.mp3-0` click (the second click) you want to (re-)add the `<object>` you removed in the previous click back inside the `#mp3obj`, not replace it. This is why the code only runs 3 click;

STOP - removes the `<object>`.

START - replaces `#mp3obj` with the `<object>`.

STOP - removes the `<object>` again.

START - ...can't find `#mp3obj` to replace with `<object>` (you replaced it!) - *function stops working...*

Try this instead:

```
$('.mp3').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('object').remove();
    $('.mp3-0').show();
});

$('.mp3-0').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#mp3obj').html('<object width="0" height="0"> <param name="src" value="musicasite.mp3"> <param name="autoplay" value="false"> <param name="controller" value="true"> <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"> <embed src="musicasite.mp3" autostart="false" loop="false" width="0" height="0" controller="true" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></embed> </object>');
    $('.mp3').show();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for your huge help with this one, really, I appreciate that.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Good luck there.